# Bitshift over Int32.max fails

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

Ok, so I have two methods

```
public static long ReadLong(this byte[] data)
{
    if (data.Length < 8) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Not enough data");

    long length = data[0] | data[1] << 8 | data[2] << 16 | data[3] << 24
            | data[4] << 32 | data[5] << 40 | data[6] << 48 | data[7] << 56;
    return length;
}
public static void WriteLong(this byte[] data, long i)
{
    if (data.Length < 8) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Not enough data");

    data[0] = (byte)((i >> (8*0)) &  0xFF);
    data[1] = (byte)((i >> (8*1)) &  0xFF);
    data[2] = (byte)((i >> (8*2)) &  0xFF);
    data[3] = (byte)((i >> (8*3)) &  0xFF);
    data[4] = (byte)((i >> (8*4)) &  0xFF);
    data[5] = (byte)((i >> (8*5)) &  0xFF);
    data[6] = (byte)((i >> (8*6)) &  0xFF);
    data[7] = (byte)((i >> (8*7)) &  0xFF);
}
```

So `WriteLong` works correctly(Verified against BitConverter.GetBytes()). The problem is `ReadLong`. I have a fairly good understanding of this stuff, but I'm guessing what's happening is the or operations are happening as 32 bit ints so at `Int32.MaxValue` it rolls over. I'm not sure how to avoid that. My first instinct was to make an int from the lower half and an int from the upper half and combine them, but I'm not quite knowledgeable to know even where to start with that, so this is what I tried....

```
public static long ReadLong(byte[] data)
{
    if (data.Length < 8) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Not enough data");

    long l1 = data[0] | data[1] << 8 | data[2] << 16 | data[3] << 24;
    long l2 = data[4] | data[5] << 8 | data[6] << 16 | data[7] << 24;
    return l1 | l2 << 32;
}
```

This didn't work though, at least not for larger numbers, it seems to work for everything below zero.

Here's how I run it

```
void Main()
{
    var larr = new long[5]{
        long.MinValue,
        0,
        long.MaxValue,
        1,
        -2000000000
    };
    foreach(var l in larr)
    {
        var arr = new byte[8];
        WriteLong(ref arr,l);
        Console.WriteLine(ByteString(arr));
        var end = ReadLong(arr);
        var end2 = BitConverter.ToInt64(arr,0);
        Console.WriteLine(l + " == " + end + " == " + end2);
    }
}
```

and here's what I get(using the modified ReadLong method)

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:128
-9223372036854775808 == -9223372036854775808 == -9223372036854775808
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0
0 == 0 == 0
255:255:255:255:255:255:255:127
9223372036854775807 == -1 == 9223372036854775807
1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0
1 == 1 == 1
0:108:202:136:255:255:255:255
-2000000000 == -2000000000 == -2000000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the or, it is the bitshift. This has to be done as longs. Currently, the data[i] are implicitely converted to int. Just change that to long and that's it. I.e.

```
 public static long ReadLong(byte[] data)
 {
     if (data.Length < 8) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Not enough data");

     long length = (long)data[0] | (long)data[1] << 8 | (long)data[2] << 16 | (long)data[3] << 24
                | (long)data[4] << 32 | (long)data[5] << 40 | (long)data[6] << 48 | (long)data[7] << 56;
     return length;
 }
```

Comment: Reference link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w.aspx "Any high-order bits that are not within the range of the type of the first operand after the shift are discarded" -- and byte has an implicit conversion to int (and `a << b` must either be `int << int`, `uint << int`, `long << int`, or `ulong << int`)

Comment: Awesome thanks! I kind of figured that was the problem, just didn't know the proper way to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing int arithmetic and then assigning to long, try:

```
long length = data[0] | data[1] << 8L | data[2] << 16L | data[3] << 24L
        | data[4] << 32L | data[5] << 40L | data[6] << 48L | data[7] << 56L;
```

This should define your constants as longs forcing it to use long arithmetic.

EDIT: Turns out this may not work according to comments below as while bitshift takes many operators on the left it only takes int on the right. Georg's should be the accepted answer.

Comment: The shift operation requires the second operand to be an `int`, or something with an implicit conversion to `int`. `8L`, etc. are `long`, not `int`. This code will not compile.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the answer to let people know so others don't try this too.